Docker Checkpoint/Restore (CRIU) Hanging on Ubuntu 24.04
Environment
Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble)
Docker 24.0.7
CRIU 4.0
Kernel: 6.8.0-48-generic
Issue
Both Docker's built-in checkpoint feature and direct CRIU usage hang when attempting to checkpoint a simple container. CRIU works for basic processes outside Docker, but fails within containers.
Example
# Start test container
docker run -d --name looper busybox /bin/sh -c 'i=0; while true; do echo $i; i=$(expr $i + 1); sleep 1; done'

# Method 1: Docker checkpoint (hangs)
docker checkpoint create looper checkpoint1

# Method 2: Direct CRIU (hangs at parasite stage)
pid=$(docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' looper)
sudo criu dump -t $pid -D /tmp/checkpoint --shell-job -v4


Docker experimental features are enabled
criu check passes

How can I successfully checkpoint a Docker container?

check your /usr/share/containers/containers.conf what is the runtime value (under [engine] ) ? - and please add the tail of the dump log so it's easier to relate
